# Multiple mobile platform game development (Android/iOS)

Tags: android, iphone

I'm currently developing a small indie game for the Android framework, however in order to save my some future work - I was wondering, is there a way to develop a game for the Android and iOS at the same time?

I'm aware of HTML 5 solutions, but I'm unsure if you can use them in order to develop games.
My requirements:
* 2D Graphics with animations
* Play sounds (music/sfx)
* Touch gestures (click, drag, pinch, etc)

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [Corona SDK](http://www.anscamobile.com/). They offer exactly what you are looking for - 2D graphics, animations, physics engine, touch, sounds; and they offer it as a cross-platform solution for both iOS and Android. The engine is OpenGL based, and they use Lua as a language.

The main drawback is that it costs $200 per platform, or $350 if you want support for both. However, you need the subscription only when you actually get to publishing your game; you can use it for free locally to build for your own device.

Comment: Side note - I am not affilieated with Ansca Mobile in any way.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, and investing 400$ in what would save me double work for nothing seems like a fair price to pay. Do you happen to know if there is a showcase or some list of games made with Coronoa SDK?

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to check Gideros Studio, which includes

- Box2D physics engine
- OpenAL sound system
- Plugins (native code support)
- Instant testing on the phone (no compile needed)
- Tweening
- Movieclips
- Sprites & sprite sheets
- Analytics
- Ad support

Using [Gideros Studio](http://www.giderosmobile.com) is free, and you can develop for both Android and iOS at the same time with native (OpenGL rendered) functions.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest writing your main game engine code in C++ because Android supports that with the NDK:

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html

And iPhone has Objective-C++ which is explained pretty well here:

[How well is Objective-C++ supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406753/how-well-is-objective-c-supported)

You're fortunate enough that both platforms use OpenGL ES, so not much will be required to port that over.

The only differences at this point will be sound, touching, file management, etc. (anything in the APIs).