# openGL ES supporting languages and portability suggestion

Tags: c#, java, android, ios, opengl-es

I been googling alot and read most of the question here but still confused and need some help to understand few things.

Me: Web developer working in C# for a long time.

Target: Develop 2D games with openGL ES 2.0 for andriod & iOS only.

Question: Which language is better to work with for openGL ES 2.0 for developing 2D games for andriod & iOS (C# or Java)?

I am really confused about choosing a language which can target most of the devices.

Thanks

Comment: Is that which language is better of C# and Java or are other options allowed?

Answer (score 2):

If you are a C# developer I would suggest to continue using it (as you need to learn a lot of new stuff for mobile development and OpenGL and by using the language you are already familiar with, you can at least avoid new language learning stress and focus yourself on new technology learning).

MonoDroid, C# for Android: 
http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid

MonoTouch, C# for iOs: 
http://xamarin.com/monotouch

No doubt that `Java` being the language of "native" support for `Android` as `Objective C` for iOS is a best choice **for platform**, but you should choose a best choice for *you*,  so I would go for C#.

Keep in mind that Mono frameworks are NOT free!

There is another interesting alternative for C++ , MoSync: http://www.mosync.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use C++ with Android via the [NDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/overview.html) and in iOS via [Objective-C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406753/how-well-is-objective-c-supported). Both use OpenGL ES so you could even share code between both platforms.

Comment: For what it's worth, I've actually done this.  It's a PITA to set up, especially on the Android side, but it DOES work.