# Create plugin for PhoneGap using a library in C++

Tags: java, c++, objective-c, cordova, plugins

I need develop a plugin for phonegap application,  it will be used for iOS, BlackBerry, Android and WindowsPhone application over PhoneGap.

I have a set of functions (library) in `C++` that allows apply operations on images, and I want to know if I can use this `C++` library to build different plugins for PhoneGAP in native code, using something like a wrapper or similar for `JAVA`, `Objective-C`, etc.

Or exist other method to use this `C++` library in multiple mobile plattforms, for instance use JNI to call the C code ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: For example on native Android, you can use C++ along with Java (You can lookup on JNI). No idea on other platforms though. You need to check for other platforms, if C++ can be used along with their respective native languages.

Comment: Well for android I can use JNI, BlackBerry use Java too, so JNI may be available, but iOS Objective-C, dont know if can call to C++ functions.

Comment: You can definitely call C++ functions in an Objective-C code. Just add the file containing your function using `#include` statement...

Comment: yes, you can use c++ on iOS apps too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759573/utilizing-c-in-ios-and-mac-os-x-applications

Answer (score -1):

no

Your answer couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.

Comment: @ManuParra `Your answer couldn't be submitted. Please see the error above.` is simply the error to warn you that your answer have an error and can't be submitted. It has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: the answer is "No" the reason why: you need different libraries, native code in Androd, android versions, Blackberrry... ans iOS...

Comment: Yes I understand, but you can call c++ functions from other languages and then integrate in each native platform

Comment: @ManuParra yes, teoretically... as how Android it is a platform independent solution, just try to wor  with Audio-Video , which require native stuff! You will see the difference between theoretically  and practically platform independency