# Porting SDL App to iOS

Tags: c++, ios, sdl, porting

I have created a small game in C++ using only SDL (no OpenGL), and want to port it to iOS 6.
I have no intention of releasing it publicly, It's just for personal use.

The app uses only the barebones SDL library itself, no ttf or image.

So, what would be the best hassle-free way of porting the game to iOS 6? The game's SDL version is 1.2, however it would be possible to port it to 2.0.

A tutorial or something similar would be of tremendous help!

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Port to 2.0, then just follow the [SDL 2.0 iOS HOWTO](https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-ios.md). SDL 2.0 has native iOS support.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that tomorrow.

Comment: That page is missing now, anyone know where it is?

Comment: @Ken I don't know how Mercurial hashes work (and if they change over time), at the moment, you can go here: http://hg.libsdl.org/SDL/file/5c42e467f6cd/docs/README-ios.md . Or, get the source via Mercurial or tarball, and read ./docs/README-ios.md relative to that unpacked directory.

Comment: They moved to GitHub and it should be here: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-ios.md