# Developing for iOS in C++ (with/without Xcode)

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c++

What are the methods of developing for `iOS` with `C++`?  I am familiar with using `Objective-C++` within Xcode, by selecting `Obj-C` as my language when creating a new project, but what else is there.  I know there are tools like Xamarin that allow for `iOS` development in `C#`, however i'm curious as to what officially supported ways of developing for `iOS` in `C++` there are?  Can an `iOS` app be written completely in `C++` with no `Objective-C` and compile?

Comment: I think you should take a look at this post https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-develop-iOS-apps-using-C++

Comment: You should see this answer :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759573/utilizing-c-in-ios-and-mac-os-x-applications

Answer (score 3):

I have an app that pretty freely intermingles Objective-C (.mm files), Objective-C++ (.m files), and C++ (.cpp) as needed. The C++ code is legacy functionality that implements the heavy lifting of our app and has worked across a number of platforms for 20+ years. No need to re-implement that.

To write a C++ object in XCode, just do it. Create .cpp and .h files like you would anywhere else.

When you need to interact with a C++ object from Objective-C, you can either go into the properties of the .m file in XCode and change it to use the Objective-C++ compiler, or (better yet) just name it .mm instead of .m. Then you can include your C++ header files with standard `#include` statements, create C++ objects with `new`, delete them with `delete`, and access members with dot notation and pointer notation just like you would from C++.

Objective-C is a lot easier to use when dealing with the UI and system calls. It isn't hard to learn. There are probably ways to access all of those objects and methods from C++, but the gymnastics you would have to do each time might make it easier to simply learn enough Objective-C (or Swift) to do those parts in the language Apple intended. (Keep in mind that to figure out how to do everything in C++ while looking at sample code and documentation that assumes Objective-C or Swift, you're going to have to master those languages anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can even go to extreme lengths to avoiding Objective-C, you won't be able to do so completely since UIKit depends on it, but nearly every other framework has a C API. Take a look at this question and the answer to it [How to write iOS app purely in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10289890/how-to-write-ios-app-purely-in-c)

C is not C++, but the answer will give you a hint on what you can do. It will involve including the objc runtime, and using objc_msgsend.