# iOS Development with C++

Tags: c++, ios, swift, xcode

I know that you are supposed to use Swift for iOS development, but I would like to use C++. Is that possible? And also, what would the graphics API look like if I chose to use C++? Would it be simply too difficult?

Comment: You can use _objective C++_, rather than just plain C++. This would allow you easy access to the APIs - they would effectively be the same as the _Objective C_ APIs. The only APIs you would not have access to would be the ones that are only available in swift.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8759573/utilizing-c-in-ios-and-mac-os-x-applications

Comment: I would recommend you learn Swift. I learned C++ before Swift, and Swift is a much better language IMO. It will also be **much** easier to get help on here for Apple platforms, as we (almost) all code in Swift.