# Does this networking library work on iOS?

Tags: c++, ios, c, networking, liblacewing

I want to use this library for cross platform networking.

http://lacewing-project.org/

It works with OSX, Linux, Windows and has specific code for Android. What I do not know is if it will work (as a client) on iOS. (meaning I will not host a server on iOS)

Since it uses POSIX sockets internally does that make it compatible with iOS?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without trying it, my guess would be that it would work. You will need to write your UI in Objective-C, but you should be able to use Objective-C++ to bind your libraries to the UI. Before you start into the Objective-C++ path be aware of the limitations (see: [How well is Objective-C++ supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406753/how-well-is-objective-c-supported)).

Comment: I'm already using a C library that is for my game graphics and all.. I will not be making UI code in Obj-C. The C graphics library Allegro 5 does it all for me. I just need to be able to have the client talk to the server.

Comment: Good to hear. I just assumed that you would be using Cocoa for UI because that's what most people do. You should be all set.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the objective-c library `AFNetworking` first, from the creators of gowalla.

You can get it here:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

On the topic of `lacewing`, it should work fine, as long as it relies upon the BSD sockets API, as I can confirm that it exists on iOS.

Comment: Unfortunately I need Windows and Linux support too.

Comment: @Milo ah. Well, in that case it may be better to use that, as I know for sure that POSIX sockets work on iOS (I have used them extensively in game development).

Comment: I should note though that I think it uses OpenSSL for encryption but that should not be a problem.

Comment: @Milo OpenSSL is also available, the Nuance Dragon Dictation API uses it.

Comment: I had someone on a forum that told me Berkley sockets don't work so well on iOS.. Something about the antenna...

Answer (score -2):

If it's only written in C/C++ then no, unless you got a C/C++ SDK for iOS (which AFAIK does not exist publicly). iOS SDK is for Objective-C.

Comment: I think you mean there are no Cocoa bindings for C++. There is a C++ SDK for iOS. It's a part of Xcode.

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C. So, any pure C library should work. Additionally, the compiler supports Objective-C++, which allows you to mix Objective-C and C++

Comment: @Dirk So if the library works on Linux and OSX without any OSX specific code, it should work on iOS? The library is pure C, but has a binding for C++.

Comment: @JefferyThomas C++ is NOT a part of Xcode, it is a part of GCC, which is what LLVM is based on, which is the default compiler that Xcode uses.

Comment: @Milo: Not necessarily. The system calls might not be available, etc. But the language is not the barrier here. That's all I wanted to say.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, I guess I should have said "It's shipped with Xcode", but I do believe there is no current version of Xcode which does not include a C++ compiler.