# Build existing C++ project for iOS and Android platform

Tags: android, c++, ios

I work for an **existing C++ project**. This project serves as a component of a larger software.

This project is supposed to support multi platforms. With all the source code and header files, the code can be built under windows, Linux and Mac. And I have .dll, .so and .dylib files for reuse.

But how about iOS and Android? I read pages and pages but I still have no idea. I cannot see how those SO Q&As and blogs relate to my problem.

Comment: There are certain frameworks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406753/how-well-is-objective-c-supported and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002164/write-applications-in-c-or-c-for-android visual studio 2015 aims to enable c++ development for both platforms and there should be lots of resources to this

Comment: @Hayt I want  some examples with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: Then stackoverflow is the wrong place for you. We are not a tutorial etc. If you have specific problems you can post them but this is too broad. If you have done some research and are stuck at some particular point you can ask. But without effort on your side you don't need to expect someone else putting effort in answering.